# How to search a substring in PHP array using regExp

Tags: regex, arrays, search, substring

```
   $array = array(
            array('foo_test1','demo_test1'),
            array('foo_test2','demo_test2'),
            array('blah_test1','exp_test1'),
            array('blah_test2','exp_test2'),
            array('foo_test3','demo_test3')
            )
```

How to get all subarray which contains `foo` substring with its value using php and regExp.

Expected Output:

```
$array = array(
        array('foo_test1','demo_test1'),
        array('foo_test2','demo_test2'),
        array('foo_test3','demo_test3')
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it with

```
preg_grep($pattern,$array)
```

Comment: This is exactly the code you need. I also searched for this function, but thought it would be called "array_match" or stg like that. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$input  = array( /* your array */ );
$output = array();

foreach ( $input as $data ) {
  $len = length($data);
  for ( $i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i ) {
    if ( strpos($data[$i], 'foo') > -1 ) {
      $output[] = $data;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
    array('foo_test1','demo_test1'),
    array('foo_test2','demo_test2'),
    array('blah_test1','exp_test1'),
    array('blah_test2','exp_test2'),
    array('foo_test3','demo_test3')
);

$search = 'foo';
$res = array();
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        if (preg_match('~'.preg_quote($search,'~').'~',$value)) {
        // if one of the values in that array
        // has the search word in it...
            $res[] = $arr; break;
            // push it into the $res and break
            // the inner foreach loop
        }
    }
}
print_r($res);
```